# How to calculate the maximum block length in C of a binary number

Tags: c, binary, block

I want to reiterate the fact that I am not asking for direct code to my problem rather than wanting information on how to reach that solution.

I asked a problem earlier about counting specific integers in binary code. Now I would like to ask how one comes about counting the maximum block length within binary code.

I honestly just want to know where to get started and what exactly the question means by writing code to figure out the "Maximum block length" of an inputted integers binary representation.

Ex: Input 456 Output: 111001000
Number of 1's: 4
Maximum Block Length: ?

Here is my code so far for reference if you need to see where I'm coming from.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int integer; // number to be entered by user
  int i, b, n;
  unsigned int ones;
  printf("Please type in a decimal integer\n"); // prompt
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%d", &integer); // read an integer

  if(integer < 0)
  {
    printf("Input value is negative!"); // if integer is less than
    fflush(stdout);

    return;                  // zero, print statement
  }
  else{
    printf("Binary Representation:\n", integer);
    fflush(stdout);} //if integer is greater than zero, print statement

    for(i = 31; i >= 0; --i) //code to convert inputted integer to binary form
    {
      b = integer >> i;
      if(b&1){
        printf("1");
        fflush(stdout);
      }
      else{
        printf("0");
        fflush(stdout);
      }
    }
  printf("\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  ones = 0; //empty value to store how many 1's are in binary code
  while(integer)  //while loop to count number of 1's within binary code
  {
    ++ones;
    integer &= integer - 1;
  }
  printf("Number of 1's in Binary Representation: %d\n", ones); // prints number
  fflush(stdout);                                           //of ones in binary code
  printf("Maximum Block Length: \n");
  fflush(stdout);
  printf("\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;

}//end function main
```

Comment: You've provided no information here to explain what you mean by "Maximum Block Length". Without a definition of the term, it's hard to explain how to get there.

Comment: Sorry, by "Maximum Block Length" I mean the greatest length of a block that a binary representation contains. 

Example: 187 is 10111011. Contains 3 blocks(the leftmost, the middle, and the rightmost). The LENGTHS of these blocks are 1, 3, and 2. Meaning that the maximum block length for this representation is 3. See where I'm getting at?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. How do you define the three blocks? I see one block of 8 bits, with a max block with of 1. Not sure what you're trying to define as a "block".

Comment: I think is talking about run length (ie how many consecutive 1 bits) and he is looking for the longest run 1's.

Comment: By "block" I mean consecutive number within the binary code(Basically both lone and pair values of 1). So when I write 10111011, there is one "block" on the leftmost(the lone 1), another in the middle(the three 1s) and the rightmost(the pair of 1's). The "length" of these blocks are 1, 3, 2(just basically the number of one's within their respective "block"). I want to know how to go about forming an array to loop through the "blocks" and get their lengths in C as I am very new to it. Whew! Did that help?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are looking for the longest run of 1's.

Heres how you do it for 32bits. You should be able to extend this idea to arbitrarily long bitstreams.

```
int maxRunLen(uint32_t num) {
    int count = 0; 
    int maxCount = 0;
    while(num) {
       if(num & 1) count++;
       else {
           if( count > maxCount) maxCount = count;
           count = 0;
       }
       num >>=1;
    }
    if( count > maxCount) maxCount = count;
    return maxCount;
}
```

The idea is to test each bit in order to determine if it is a 1 or not. If it is 1, increment the count. Otherwise it is the end of a run and in this case check if the previous run is longer than any previous maximum run and reset the count.

The way to test a bit is using masking. In the above example the lowest order bit tested by

```
num & 1
```

To test the next bit in the number you move all the bits 1 bit to the right which is called a shift. More explicitly in this a case a logical right shift (>>). Example bit pattern 0110 becomes 0011. This is done in the above example:

```
num >>= 1;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
num = num >> 1;
```

Comment: Is there a way to alter this to keep it within one function(in my case the int main(void) function.

Comment: @user1664272 yes, but you stated: "I honestly just want to know where to get started...". I can do it, but I think the exercise of you doing it will benefit you greater than me telling you.

Comment: Oh jeez you're right. I jumped the gun on almost slacking, I apologize. Thank you for contributing though, this will help me greatly. Off to work!

Comment: @user1664272 If you have specific questions on how it works, go ahead and ask. If you are happy with the answer you should accept it.

Comment: @user1664272 Added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: The problem I'm encountering now is that I keep getting a consistent value of 3 for the maximum block length! Technically it would be correct if someone chose to convert a number within the hundreds into binary form, but I want to be as accurate as possible! I'll link my code in a little bit, maybe I am missing a variable.

Comment: I'm using:
unsigned int num;

Is this why it isn't working? I feel as though I need to give num a value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int max_run_of_ones (unsigned x)
{
  int max_run = 0;
  int cur_run;

  while (x != 0) {
    // skip right-most zeros                                                    
    while ((x & 1) == 0) {
      x >>= 1;
    }
    // skip and measure right-most run of ones                                  
    cur_run = 0;
    while ((x & 1) == 1) {
      cur_run++;
      x >>= 1;
    }
    if (cur_run > max_run) max_run = cur_run;
  }
  return max_run;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, it looks like you want to know the count of the bits set.
This is a guess...

Credit goes to Ratko Tomic for this.  The guy is brilliant at bit operations.

```
int countBits( int value )
{
    int n = 0;

    if( value )
    {
        do
        {
            n++;
        } while( 0 != (value = value & (value - 1) ) );
    }
    return( n );
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what he's looking for. If you have a binary representation of a number as 10110111011010. In that number, there are 5 "blocks", of length 1, 2, 3, 2, 1. So the max block length is 3.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it in python, using string operations...

The main point of this is to help others with understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

```
import re    

number = 500
binary_repr = bin(number)[2:]             # '111110100'
blocks = re.split(r'0+', binary_repr)     # ['11111', '1', '']
block_lengths = [len(x) for x in blocks]  # [5, 1, 0]
maximum_block_length = max(block_lengths) # 5
```

Comment: I should mention that I must do this in C and I'm not very well experienced in coding. I can't interpret Python code at all, my apologies.

Comment: That's fine, this is almost more for the people commenting than it is for you. James solution is more along what you're looking for I think. I only used python because it's simple to rapidly write functional code.

Comment: No problem, I also forget that others look at this who may code in different languages. I'm more so happy that this is a topic that sparked some radical thinking, I feel like I contributed a worthwhile question :)